# shell script prompting for password but not taking it while doing tar

Tags: bash, password, tar

In my shell script, I have following lines:

```
function tarIt() {
  FILE_OWNER=$1
  TAR_FILE_NAME=$2
  FILE_NAME=$3

  su - $FILE_OWNER -c "tar -czf $TAR_FILE_NAME $FILE_NAME 2>&1"
  if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]; then
      print_error "Failed to create backup.";
      exit $E_FAILED_COMPRESS;
  fi
}
```

While debugging, I am getting below lines:

```
+ su - ssrun -c 'tar -cvzf /tmp/backup/statusService/probe.properties.tar.gz /opt/mgtservices/probes/conf/probe.properties 2>&1'
Password: ssrun1
su: incorrect password
+ '[' 125 -ne 0 ']'
+ print_error 'Failed to create backup.'
```

I don't know while prompting for password, why my text is visible and password also it is not taking. The password is correct, when I copied the same line on command prompt, it executed without any error.

Below is the script uploaded. This has utlitiy methods which I am calling from another script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit Status
E_DIR_NOT_EXIST=55;            # error if directory does not exist
E_DIR_PERMISSION_DENIED=77;    # error if directory does not exist

if [ -z "${V9UPGRADE_LOG}" ]
then
      LOGFILE=/tmp/${SCRIPTNAME}.$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').log;
else
       LOGFILE=${V9UPGRADE_LOG};
fi

# Verifies the run user or root user
if ! [[ $(whoami) =~ ^(ssrun|root)$ ]]
then
      print_error "You have to be user ssrun or root to perform this operation.";
      exit ${E_USER};
fi

# Function to log information
function print_info() {
    format="$1"
    shift
      printf "$(date +'%F %T') ${SCRIPTNAME}: INFO: $format\n" "$@" | tee -a ${LOGFILE};
}

# Function to log warning
function print_warn() {
    format="$1"
    shift
      printf "$(date +'%F %T') ${SCRIPTNAME}: WARN: $format\n" "$@" | tee -a ${LOGFILE};
}

# Function to log error
function print_error() {
    format="$1"
    shift
      printf "$(date +'%F %T') ${SCRIPTNAME}: ERROR: $format\n" "$@" | tee -a ${LOGFILE} >&2;
}

function validateDir4Permission() {
    DIR=$1
    [ -d $DIR ] || { print_error "Invalid directory $DIR"; exit $E_DIR_NOT_EXIST; }
    ( su - $RUNUSR -c "[[ -rwx $DIR ]]" ) || { print_error "$DIR has insufficient permissions for ssrun user"; exit $E_DIR_PERMISSION_DENIED; }
    ( su - $ESYUSR -c "[[ -rwx $DIR ]]" ) || { print_error "$DIR has insufficient permissions for ne3suser user"; exit $E_DIR_PERMISSION_DENIED; }
    [[ -rwx $DIR ]] || { print_error "$DIR has insufficient permissions for current user"; exit $E_DIR_PERMISSION_DENIED; }
}

# Function to append ".tar.gz" to name of file
function getArchiveFileName() {
    echo ${SS_BACKUP_DIR}/${1}.tar.gz
}

# Function to compress the files and store in backup directory.
function tarIt() {
    FILE_NAME=$1
    TAR_FILE_NAME=$(getArchiveFileName $2)
    FILE_OWNER=$3
    if [[ -f $TAR_FILE_NAME ]]; then
        print_info "$TAR_FILE_NAME already exists. Removing current instance.";
        rm -f $TAR_FILE_NAME;
    fi

    su - $FILE_OWNER -c "tar -zcf $TAR_FILE_NAME $FILE_NAME > 2>&1"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        print_error "Failed to compress $TAR_FILE_NAME."
        exit $E_FAILED_COMPRESS;
    else
        if [[ -f $FILE_NAME ]]; then
            print_info "File %s is backed up at %s" "$FILE_NAME" "$SS_BACKUP_DIR"
        else
            print_info "$All the contents of directory %s are compressed to %s." "$FILE_NAME" "$TAR_FILE_NAME"
        fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: press `ctrl+j` rather than return.

Comment: @mikeserv I didn't got your point, where I need to do `ctrl + j`

Comment: Use double quotes for $1, $2, ... ("$1", "$2", ...)

Comment: option `-v` of tar is for verbose, then `> /dev/null` ... sight.

Comment: @A.B. didn't work, when I am executing the script from root user, it works fine, since root don't need password for "su" here, but when I am executing this script from child user, I am facing this problem

Comment: After entering the password when you would usually press `enter` or `return` to submit the password, try pressing `ctrl+j` instead to avoid appending the `\r`eturn to the password and send only a `\n`ewline instead.

Comment: Can you give us more information? How are you calling the script, what parameters do you use? Are there more code?

Comment: Please post a complete script that exhibits the problem (a complete script starts with `#!`). On what operating system (variant, distribution) are you running this? How are you running the script?

Comment: Your uploaded script doesn't have `/dev/null` in the line `su - $FILE_OWNER -c "tar -zcf $TAR_FILE_NAME $FILE_NAME > 2>&1"`.

Comment: @ott--I removed it as I got comment on it to remove /dev/null and -v from tar.